# Jobs order in Quartz

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

Currently I'm working with Quartz and met a problem: I need to run tasks in some order, e.g. one by one. Is it possible to implement it using Quartz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a task/job-chain feature.

You could either implement it by yourself or rely on quartz provided [JobChainingJobListener](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/listeners/JobChainingJobListener.html)

simple example:

```
chainListener = new JobChainingJobListener( "myChainListener" );
chainListener.addJobChainLink( job1.getKey(), job2.getKey() );

sched.scheduleJob( job1, trigger );
sched.addJob( job2, true );
sched.addGlobalJobListener( chainListener ); 
  sched.start();
```

you could get more examples/explaination if you try to google it, I believe.

At least it gives you a start.

Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible. I was going to suggest to use a [StatefulJob](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/StatefulJob.html) but turns out it's deprecated meanwhile. They say to use the `DisallowConcurrentExecution` annotation instead, so you can go with that.
Both prevent the execution of a second job before the current one is finished. The execution of the second job is delayed until the first one has finished. Right after the first one has finished, the delayed one gets started.

Comment: statefulljob prevents concurrent executions of the same job, not the thing OP was asking.